# Async/Await with Axios getting stuck

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, axios, bluebird

Here is what i am trying to do: i am looping through a json file full of links of our website using a for loop(around 3000 links), inside the loop i am doing a axios get for each link and getting the response status code(will do other things in the future). My code is getting stuck at random iteration , Some time at 125th link sometime 178, some time 300. My console just sits there with no error [image]

Seems like at certain links at random the get request is taking too long, how do i skip a link that is taking too long or maybe can i set a timeout for each get request and if nothing return in that certain time skip that iteration?

I tried putting try catch everywhere and nothing is logging, i also tried with blubird map instead of loop and it's the same deal, Anyone have any idea what's going on ?

```js
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');
var four04 = "404";
var statusCheck = 0;

var main = [];
let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('C:/Users/jay/Documents/crawl/filtered.json');
let jsonParsed = JSON.parse(rawdata);

async function makeRequests (lines) {
    for (const line of lines) {


      try {
        const encodedLink = encodeURI(line.link)
        statusCheck =statusCheck+1
        console.log(encodedLink +" : "+ statusCheck)
        const response = await axios.get(encodedLink)
        console.log(response.status)

      } catch (error) {

          var Status_ErrorsCatch = {
              "status Code": error.response.status ? error.response.status : "No status code available",
              "Page title:": $('title').text() ? $('title').text() : 'No title avaialble',
              "Original Link": encodedLink ? encodedLink : "No Original Link Available",
          }
          main.push(Status_ErrorsCatch)
      }
    }

  }
  
  try {
    makeRequests(jsonParsed)

  } catch (error) {
      console.log("whole function error",error)
  }
```

Comment: It is possible that you are being rate limited. Rather than ask for potential solutions to such a broad question, please try different solutions yourself and come back to ask if/when you get stuck.

Comment: @MichaelCheng used a new promise and set a timeout for 15 minutes after every multiple of 40 , meaning after every 40 request  the code take a 15 minute break, but still same issue happening. `  if (statusCheck % 40 === 0) {
     
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 900000))

        }`